# On notation for function mapping

Tags: functions

How can I write the following multiple mappings in a more compact and elegant way?

$$
\begin{align}
  \bar \mu \leq 0&: \lim \limits_{\rho  \to \infty } \mu  \to 0 \\
  \bar \mu \geq 1&: \lim \limits_{\rho  \to \infty } \mu  \to 1 \\
  \bar \mu  \in (0,1)&: \lim\limits_{\rho  \to \infty } \mu  \to \bar \mu   \\ 
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking.  Please add some context to your question.  In particular, what is $\rho$, and how does $\mu$ depend on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your notation makes little sense to me, but I think what you are trying to say can be written as follows:
$$ \lim_{\rho\to\infty}\mu=\begin{cases}0&\bar\mu\le0\\1&\bar\mu\ge1\\\bar\mu&\bar\mu\in(0,1)\end{cases}$$

Comment: It is a definite improvement! Thanks.